# Семантика союза 'но' в случае 'не' с прилагательным

Tags: семантика, союзы, частица-не, прилагательные

Розенталь, справ. по р. яз. [§ 57. Частица не с прилагательными](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77):

> При использовании союза но соединяемые понятия **не противопоставляются** друг другу

Викисловарь: [но](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%BE), cемантические свойства:

> обозначает **противопоставление** или противоречащих одно другому или ограничивающих слов или предложений
>
> начиная собой предложение, вводит новую мысль, **противоположную** не последнему сказанному слову или предложению, а всему, что перед тем высказано

Вопрос: верно ли, что при совместом исп-ии частицы 'не' с прилагательным и союза 'но' меняется семантика союза 'но' (противопоставление меняется на непротивопоставление)?

Comment: не огромный, но большой  - "но" не отрицание, а уточнение.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конструкции с союзом НО, о которых говорит Розенталь, **действительно не содержат отрицания** по сравнению с конструкциями с  союзом А, хотя оба союза относятся **к группе противительных союзов**. Но при построении таких оборотов учитываются **частные значения союзов.**

1. У Розенталя § 57. Частица НЕ с прилагательными
   http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77, пункт 3

Различается **противопоставление, выраженное союзом А, и противопоставление, выраженное союзом НО.** При использовании союза А один из двух противоположных друг другу признаков отрицается, а другой — утверждается: река не глубокая, а мелкая — раздельное написание отрицательной частицы.

При использовании союза НО соединяемые понятия не противопоставляются друг другу, так как они вполне совместимы, т. е. предмету одновременно приписываются два признака без отрицания одного из них: река неглубокая, но холодная — слитное написание отрицательной частицы.

**2. В грамматике**

Сочинительные союзы делятся на с**оединительные, противительные и разделительные,** а противительные союзы могут выражать **сопоставительные и противительные** отношения.

**При сопоставлении** факты различаются по какому-либо признаку, но не исключают друг друга, а сосуществуют. **При противительных отношениях** события противоречат, не соответствуют или мешают друг другу.

**Союз А** является основным сопоставительным союзом, а **союз НО** — основным противительным союзом, однако в частных случаях они **могут заменять** друг друга.

В конструкции, которую обычно называют **противопоставлением**, используется **сопоставительный союз А и частица НЕ**: ***река не глубокая, а мелкая.*** Здесь сопоставляются противоположные признаки (антонимы), при это один из них отрицается, а другой утверждается.

**В конструкции с союзом НО** признаки совместимы и не отрицают друг друга, так как используется частное **противительно-уступительное значение союза НО:** вторая часть сообщения **НЕ СООТВЕТСТВУЕТ** **ожидаемому следствию** первой части. ***Река неглубокая, но холодная.*** (Обычно неглубокие реки хорошо прогреваются, и вода в них теплая.) **Так можно объяснить использование союза НО.**

**Приложение**

Кустова Г. Синтаксис современного русского языка, стр. 226
[https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf](https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf)

**Существуют частные значения противительных отношений.**

**1. Противительно-ограничительное: (НО)**

Событие во второй части препятствует осуществлению действия в первой части, ограничивает, сужает сферу его распространения; в случае ограничительного уточнения — ограничивает или уточняет сферу его распространения: Фрида протянула обе руки Маргарите, но Коровьев и Бегемот очень ловко подхватили ее под руки, и ее затерло в толпе (Б.). Я бы с ним встретился, но сегодня у меня нет времени.

**2. Противительно-уступительное (НО, ХОТЯ)**

Действие второй части противоречит естественному следствию из действия первой части: Я очень устал, но все-таки решил сделать русский язык, Его имя Вернер, но он русский (Л.).

**3. Противительно-возместительное: (ЗАТО, НО)**

Какой-либо недостаток явления в первой части возмещается каким-либо его достоинством во второй части; или положительно оцениваемая ситуация В компенсирует отрицательно оцениваемую ситуацию А: Петя тяжелый человек, зато он хороший программист. Он совершенно приучился голодать по вечерам; но зато он питался духовно, нося в мыслях своих вечную идею будущей шинели (Г.).

Answer (score 1):

не огромный, но большой  - "но" не отрицание, а уточнение. а если будет огромный-крошечный, то "не огромный, а маленький".

в педивикии какая-то хрень написана. "но" это не про противопоставление, а про изменение угла зрения слушающего.  Старый, но(ещё) сильный конь - не подумай, что он старый и слабый, он пока в силе - сильный. Ребенок был резов, но мил, - ребенок был резв, но не подумай, что противный, он милый. Нельзя противопоставить что-то неназванному состоянию, это алогично.

"Но" акцентирует, что человек склонен считать что-то более важным, чем сказанное до "но" или вне "но" конструкции.

- *— Променять место подле вас — ни за что! — Но оно уже обещано.* - важнее то, что место уже обещана, чем остальные слова.
- ... Но я все-таки не согласен.
- *— Но, прежде, чем драться, вы извольте показать мне, как нужно стрелять.* - но вы покажете как стрелять, а после - хоть драться.
- *Старый, но сильный конь*, - не смотри, что старый, главное - он сильный.